# Client-Server application for Android with Netty integration

Tags: android, sockets, netty

I need to develop an application on Android platform that enables a client to communicate/request a command to the server and enables the server to response to the client's request.

I read about Netty and I want to implement it to my project but I'm new to socket programming, it was written in Java, so implementing it to Android is not that hard, I guess. I'm looking for examples online but I'm lost in finding a good example for Android.

Can someone here can give me example/s to start with or tell me how can I achieve those features to my application?

Comment: Are you sure Netty works on Android? Are you sure it's not overkill?

Comment: ah yes, i saw forums too that Netty works at Android, i just don't know where to start and how to start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netty supports both NIO and OIO, but Android has broken support for NIO, so you can only use the OIO (blocking I/O) transport.  Also, SSLEngine in Android is also broken, which mean, you can't implement SSL with Netty on Android. (or possible probably using an alternative socket factory?)

Therefore, I would not recommend using Netty for Android devices although it's also true that many people seems to use Netty on Android successfully somehow.

Comment: What is your suggestion for android client to connect netty server ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Android has broken support for NIO'? I googled `android nio broken support` but cannot find related information. I'm about to use netty on Android for nio therefore I think it's safer to ask first.

Comment: You are correct.  The issues that prevented people from using NIO in Android were all fixed before ICS, and that's why Netty is going to support Android officially from its next major release: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2127

Answer (score 0):

Netty is an asynchronous event-driven network application framework. (asynch I/O, Java NIO, high-performance)
I think that Netty is a valuable framework for multiple client connection or multiple server connection.

Android devices normally have very limited resources.

I would recommend that you use java blocking socket at android devices.

Comment: can you give an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Netty on Android as it is taking some javassist classes which are not recognized by the Android VM (Dalvik) such as the javassist.ClassPool class. Take a good old java socket, and wrap it around a nice helper class and it should do it.